# MySQL - отсортировать номера строк

Tags: mysqli, сортировка, phpmyadmin, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно отсортировать номера, не затронув названия?

[image: img]

Comment: Извините, что это значит? Вы хотите перенумеровать строки, не нарушая порядка имён, начиная с `1 Авдееевка`, '2 Акимовка` и т.д.? А что не получается с Вашим запросом, только вместо

    order by ordering

--

    order by `name_ru-RU`

Comment: @uzumaxy у него был почти нормальный запрос...

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Создайте такую же пустую таблицу с автоинкрементом.
запросом 
`INSERT INTO <copy_table> (name_ru-RU) 
SELECT 
 name_ru-RU
FROM <src_table>
ORDER BY name_ru-RU`
Автоинкремент сам проставится.
Затем старую таблицу удалите а новую переименуете в старую.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET ordering=0
```

&&

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET ordering=((SELECT MAX(ordering) FROM <table_name>)+1)
ORDER BY name_ru-RU
```

Где `<table_name>` - название таблицы.

Comment: проверяли? нельзя апдейтить таблицу по выборке из нее же.

Comment: Как Я понял, речь идет не о выборке. Автору нужно изменить нумерацию "ordering" в соответствии с name_ru-RU, что упорядочен по-алфавиту.
Может быть Я что-то не так понял, лучше бы автор более детально описал суть проблемы.

Comment: вы действительно не поняли. но не то о чем спрашивал ТС, а то, что ваш вариант работать не будет.